# How to update my Edge extension in MS partner center - unable to see it because of wrong tenant or something

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-edge-extension

I have a strange problem as I am unable to get access to my Edge extension in the Partner Center and update it to a new version. Have done this in the past with no problems

I login from here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/?form=MA13LH

I see 2 AD folders (Password Crypt is the correct one), but I have no access to my extension on the start page.

[image]

This may be because it shows the one from benny@beast.dk but how do I change it? When I go into account settings I can see that Password Crypt is default, but on the start page it looks as seen above.

I have another developer account for SCIM development where I worked on an extension a long time ago. When I login with this user everything is normal and I can se this un-published extension right away.

Hope somebody can help me with the simple stupid problem?

/Benny